# What's significance of return statement here?

Tags: c++, recursion, coding-style, bitset, n-queens

What is the significance of the return statement here? [ question : N_queen problem ] When I call without using return, the function works. But it doesn't work when I use the return statement in a recursive call [I have mentioned in the code]. Please explain, and if possible can you please explain by tracing out the calls (ie, how the control moves)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;

bitset<30> cols,diag1,diag2; //all zeros

void Nqueen(int n,int row, int& ans){
    if(row==n){
        ans++;
        return;
    }
    //moving across each column
    //k is iterator for columns
    for(int k=0;k<n;k++){
        if(!cols[k] && !diag1[row+k] && !diag2[row-k+n-1]){
            cols[k]=diag1[row+k]=diag2[row-k+n-1]=1;
            Nqueen(n,row+1,ans);   //this recursion call I am talking about.
            
            // if I comment out the above recursion call and instead write
            // return (Nqueen(n,rows+1,ans));
            // It outputs 0 for any input n

            cols[k]=diag1[row+k]=diag2[row-k+n-1]=0; //backtracking
        }
    }
} 
    
int main(){
    int n; cin>>n; //size of board(square matrix)
    int ans=0;
    Nqueen(n,0,ans);//0 is for 1st row
    cout<<ans<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Read some good [C++ programming book](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html) then read some C++ standard like [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) or better. Read also the documentation of your C++ compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...). Compile your C++ code with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` then use `gdb` to understand the behavior of your program

Comment: Read also the wikipedia page about the [Call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) and the page about [automatic variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable).

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in the optimization that the compiler will perform with the knowledge that the function is `void`, meaning there is no need to return any value.

When you use the `return (Nqueen(n,row+1,ans));` you are instructing the compiler to generate a code that will compute the value of `Nqueen` than return it to the caller of the function. However since the function is `void` the compiler will understand that there is no need to execute the computation since it wont be returned so he will generate a return only.

If you want to see what compiler did, you can translate both version in assembler with passing the `-S` flag to the compiler and compare the difference. Following is the difference between both version in aarch64 (arm64) assembler:

```
diff test-normal.s test-return.s
2c2
<   .file   "test-normal.cpp"
---
>   .file   "test-return.cpp"
265,309c265
<   ldrsw   x0, [sp, 68]
<   add x1, sp, 72
<   mov x8, x1
<   mov x1, x0
<   adrp    x0, cols
<   add x0, x0, :lo12:cols
<   bl  _ZNSt6bitsetILm30EEixEm
<   ldr w1, [sp, 56]
<   ldr w0, [sp, 68]
<   add w0, w1, w0
<   sxtw    x0, w0
<   add x1, sp, 88
<   mov x8, x1
<   mov x1, x0
<   adrp    x0, diag1
<   add x0, x0, :lo12:diag1
<   bl  _ZNSt6bitsetILm30EEixEm
<   ldr w1, [sp, 56]
<   ldr w0, [sp, 68]
<   sub w1, w1, w0
<   ldr w0, [sp, 60]
<   add w0, w1, w0
<   sub w0, w0, #1
<   sxtw    x0, w0
<   add x1, sp, 104
<   mov x8, x1
<   mov x1, x0
<   adrp    x0, diag2
<   add x0, x0, :lo12:diag2
<   bl  _ZNSt6bitsetILm30EEixEm
<   add x0, sp, 104
<   mov w1, 0
<   bl  _ZNSt6bitsetILm30EE9referenceaSEb
<   mov x1, x0
<   add x0, sp, 88
<   bl  _ZNSt6bitsetILm30EE9referenceaSERKS1_
<   mov x1, x0
<   add x0, sp, 72
<   bl  _ZNSt6bitsetILm30EE9referenceaSERKS1_
<   add x0, sp, 104
<   bl  _ZNSt6bitsetILm30EE9referenceD1Ev
<   add x0, sp, 88
<   bl  _ZNSt6bitsetILm30EE9referenceD1Ev
<   add x0, sp, 72
<   bl  _ZNSt6bitsetILm30EE9referenceD1Ev
---
>   b   .L7
```

As you can see, the difference is that in the normal case, the compiler generated the code for the recursion, while in the case with the return statement, generated a single `b` (branch) instruction to return whiteout computation. So, the compiler optimized the generated code since it understood that the computed value will never be return.